# How to replace namespace with xslt

Tags: xslt, namespaces

I need to change the namespace from `http://tempuri.org/` to `http://sergio/service/teste`

Following is the input XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ns0:RecuperarCopiaResponse xmlns:ns0="http://tempuri.org/">
<ns0:RecuperarCopiaResult><![CDATA[<Abastecimento_NF ULTIMO_PONTEIRO="447050"><Abastecimento_NFRow><DT_PROCESS>6/2/2018 1:46:08</DT_PROCESS><CD_ABASTECIMENTO>123936138</CD_ABASTECIMENTO><CD_VEICULO>479077</CD_VEICULO><CD_TIPO_REGISTRO>1</CD_TIPO_REGISTRO><NR_BANCO>237</NR_BANCO><CD_REDE>801</CD_REDE><DC_REDE>801</DC_REDE><COD_POSTO>244</COD_POSTO><COD_FROTA>4941</COD_FROTA><COD_SUBFROTA>11264</COD_SUBFROTA><DC_SUBFROTA>R2C</DC_SUBFROTA><CD_COMBUSTIVEL>S</CD_COMBUSTIVEL><DC_COMBUSTIVEL>S</DC_COMBUSTIVEL><NR_UVE></NR_UVE><DC_PLACA>KWG8687</DC_PLACA><NM_MOTORISTA></NM_MOTORISTA><NR_KM_ATUAL>226076</NR_KM_ATUAL><NR_QTD_LITROS>139,55</NR_QTD_LITROS><VL_PRECO_UNITARIO>3,798</VL_PRECO_UNITARIO><VL_PRECO_AEP>3,798</VL_PRECO_AEP><VL_VALOR_TOTAL>530,01</VL_VALOR_TOTAL><DT_EVENTO>5/2/2018 14:37:00</DT_EVENTO><DT_DEBITO>26/2/2018 0:00:00</DT_DEBITO><DT_CREDITO>27/2/2018 0:00:00</DT_CREDITO><NOMEARQ>T2060218.ZZ001305.00244</NOMEARQ><NR_KM_PERCORRIDA>365</NR_KM_PERCORRIDA><NR_QTD_LITROS_TOTAL>139,55</NR_QTD_LITROS_TOTAL><CD_STATUS_ABASTECIMENTO>S</CD_STATUS_ABASTECIMENTO><DC_STATUS_ABASTECIMENTO>TOTAL</DC_STATUS_ABASTECIMENTO><DC_NOME_FANTASIA>POSTO DE COMB. CONTORNO DE CAMPOS LTDA</DC_NOME_FANTASIA><DC_CIDADE_COR>CAMPOS DOS GOYTACAZES</DC_CIDADE_COR><NR_CNPJ>31212889000102</NR_CNPJ><PONTEIRO>447050</PONTEIRO><DAT_PROCESSAMENTO_NF>8/2/2018 9:48:05</DAT_PROCESSAMENTO_NF><DSC_NUMERO_NOTA_FISCAL>7507</DSC_NUMERO_NOTA_FISCAL><DSC_CHAVE></DSC_CHAVE><DSC_SERIE></DSC_SERIE></Abastecimento_NFRow></Abastecimento_NF>]]>
</ns0:RecuperarCopiaResult>
</ns0:RecuperarCopiaResponse>
```

I am using the following xslt code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:ns0="enablon">
<xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
<xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
</xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="ns0:*">
  <xsl:element name="ns0:{local-name()}" 
 namespace="http://www.supergasbras.com.br/service/CtfAbastecimento">
     <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
  </xsl:element>
 </xsl:template>
 <xsl:template match="text()">
  <xsl:value-of select="." disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Using this XSLT code, I am getting the following XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ns0:RecuperarCopiaResponse xmlns:ns0="http://tempuri.org/">
 <ns0:RecuperarCopiaResult>
  <Abastecimento_NF ULTIMO_PONTEIRO="447050">
     <Abastecimento_NFRow>
        <DT_PROCESS>6/2/2018 1:46:08</DT_PROCESS>
        <CD_ABASTECIMENTO>123936138</CD_ABASTECIMENTO>
        <CD_VEICULO>479077</CD_VEICULO>
        <CD_TIPO_REGISTRO>1</CD_TIPO_REGISTRO>
        <NR_BANCO>237</NR_BANCO>
        <CD_REDE>801</CD_REDE>
        <DC_REDE>801</DC_REDE>
        <COD_POSTO>244</COD_POSTO>
        <COD_FROTA>4941</COD_FROTA>
        <COD_SUBFROTA>11264</COD_SUBFROTA>
        <DC_SUBFROTA>R2C</DC_SUBFROTA>
        <CD_COMBUSTIVEL>S</CD_COMBUSTIVEL>
        <DC_COMBUSTIVEL>S</DC_COMBUSTIVEL>
        <NR_UVE/>
        <DC_PLACA>KWG8687</DC_PLACA>
        <NM_MOTORISTA/>
        <NR_KM_ATUAL>226076</NR_KM_ATUAL>
        <NR_QTD_LITROS>139,55</NR_QTD_LITROS>
        <VL_PRECO_UNITARIO>3,798</VL_PRECO_UNITARIO>
        <VL_PRECO_AEP>3,798</VL_PRECO_AEP>
        <VL_VALOR_TOTAL>530,01</VL_VALOR_TOTAL>
        <DT_EVENTO>5/2/2018 14:37:00</DT_EVENTO>
        <DT_DEBITO>26/2/2018 0:00:00</DT_DEBITO>
        <DT_CREDITO>27/2/2018 0:00:00</DT_CREDITO>
        <NOMEARQ>T2060218.ZZ001305.00244</NOMEARQ>
        <NR_KM_PERCORRIDA>365</NR_KM_PERCORRIDA>
        <NR_QTD_LITROS_TOTAL>139,55</NR_QTD_LITROS_TOTAL>
        <CD_STATUS_ABASTECIMENTO>S</CD_STATUS_ABASTECIMENTO>
        <DC_STATUS_ABASTECIMENTO>TOTAL</DC_STATUS_ABASTECIMENTO>
        <DC_NOME_FANTASIA>POSTO DE COMB. CONTORNO DE CAMPOS LTDA</DC_NOME_FANTASIA>
        <DC_CIDADE_COR>CAMPOS DOS GOYTACAZES</DC_CIDADE_COR>
        <NR_CNPJ>31212889000102</NR_CNPJ>
        <PONTEIRO>447050</PONTEIRO>
        <DAT_PROCESSAMENTO_NF>8/2/2018 9:48:05</DAT_PROCESSAMENTO_NF>
        <DSC_NUMERO_NOTA_FISCAL>7507</DSC_NUMERO_NOTA_FISCAL>
        <DSC_CHAVE/>
        <DSC_SERIE/>
     </Abastecimento_NFRow>
  </Abastecimento_NF>
</ns0:RecuperarCopiaResult>
```

Following is the expected XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <ns0:RecuperarCopiaResponse xmlns:ns0="http://sergio/service/teste">
  <ns0:RecuperarCopiaResult>
  <Abastecimento_NF ULTIMO_PONTEIRO="447050">
     <Abastecimento_NFRow>
        <DT_PROCESS>6/2/2018 1:46:08</DT_PROCESS>
        <CD_ABASTECIMENTO>123936138</CD_ABASTECIMENTO>
        <CD_VEICULO>479077</CD_VEICULO>
        <CD_TIPO_REGISTRO>1</CD_TIPO_REGISTRO>
        <NR_BANCO>237</NR_BANCO>
        <CD_REDE>801</CD_REDE>
        <DC_REDE>801</DC_REDE>
        <COD_POSTO>244</COD_POSTO>
        <COD_FROTA>4941</COD_FROTA>
        <COD_SUBFROTA>11264</COD_SUBFROTA>
        <DC_SUBFROTA>R2C</DC_SUBFROTA>
        <CD_COMBUSTIVEL>S</CD_COMBUSTIVEL>
        <DC_COMBUSTIVEL>S</DC_COMBUSTIVEL>
        <NR_UVE/>
        <DC_PLACA>KWG8687</DC_PLACA>
        <NM_MOTORISTA/>
        <NR_KM_ATUAL>226076</NR_KM_ATUAL>
        <NR_QTD_LITROS>139,55</NR_QTD_LITROS>
        <VL_PRECO_UNITARIO>3,798</VL_PRECO_UNITARIO>
        <VL_PRECO_AEP>3,798</VL_PRECO_AEP>
        <VL_VALOR_TOTAL>530,01</VL_VALOR_TOTAL>
        <DT_EVENTO>5/2/2018 14:37:00</DT_EVENTO>
        <DT_DEBITO>26/2/2018 0:00:00</DT_DEBITO>
        <DT_CREDITO>27/2/2018 0:00:00</DT_CREDITO>
        <NOMEARQ>T2060218.ZZ001305.00244</NOMEARQ>
        <NR_KM_PERCORRIDA>365</NR_KM_PERCORRIDA>
        <NR_QTD_LITROS_TOTAL>139,55</NR_QTD_LITROS_TOTAL>
        <CD_STATUS_ABASTECIMENTO>S</CD_STATUS_ABASTECIMENTO>
        <DC_STATUS_ABASTECIMENTO>TOTAL</DC_STATUS_ABASTECIMENTO>
        <DC_NOME_FANTASIA>POSTO DE COMB. CONTORNO DE CAMPOS 
          LTDA</DC_NOME_FANTASIA>
        <DC_CIDADE_COR>CAMPOS DOS GOYTACAZES</DC_CIDADE_COR>
        <NR_CNPJ>31212889000102</NR_CNPJ>
        <PONTEIRO>447050</PONTEIRO>
        <DAT_PROCESSAMENTO_NF>8/2/2018 9:48:05</DAT_PROCESSAMENTO_NF>
        <DSC_NUMERO_NOTA_FISCAL>7507</DSC_NUMERO_NOTA_FISCAL>
        <DSC_CHAVE/>
        <DSC_SERIE/>
      </Abastecimento_NFRow>
   </Abastecimento_NF>
 </ns0:RecuperarCopiaResult>
</ns0:RecuperarCopiaResponse>
```

Regards,
Sérgio Salomão

Comment: In your XSLT you have declared the namespace as `xmlns:ns0="enablon"` when it should match your XML and be `xmlns:ns0="http://tempuri.org/"`

Comment: And the namespace URI for output should be `http://sergio/service/teste` not `http://www.supergasbras.com.br/service/CtfAbastecimento`

Comment: Thank you. It worked. Regards.